# How do I perform arithmetic operations on variables in HIVE?

Tags: variables, hadoop, hive

I need to call all the weeks between two values: 201701 and 201710 , They are the first and 10th week of 2017 .

I created a variable

```
set var1 = 201710 ;
```

Now I want to use this variable to get the dates like :

```
select * from table1 where dates between ${hiveconf:var1} - 10 and ${hiveconf:var1} ;
```

but I guess I am messing up somewhere with the syntax .

However, I am able to work on queries like :

```
select * from table 1 where dates >= ${hiveconf:var1}
```

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Your query works good on Hive 1.2.1000.2.4.3.3-2

Comment: (1) What's the problem (2) what is the type/format of `dates`?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz  (1) I'm unable to execute the between query (2) the date formats are integers

Comment: Error? ...............

Comment: I dont get any results

Comment: No, the date mentioned is the latest. Are you sure there is nothing wrong with the syntax in the query ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142181/discussion-between-vinay-billa-and-dudu-markovitz).

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you are storing single digit weeks without a preceding `0`, e.g. -
 `20179` instead of `201709`